# ¿Cómo centrar imagen en div?

Tags: css

Estoy centrando una imagen en un div, funciona bien en chrome, pero en Internet Explorer no se centra bien, ¿pueden guiarme?

Éste es mi código:

```css
.imgUser {
  display: flex;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
}

.imgUser img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 250px; text-align: center; float: left; background-color: gray; ">

  <div class="imgUser">
    <img src="img.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: [Internet Explorer no termina de soportar bien FlexBox](https://caniuse.com/#search=justify-content). Eso puede ser el motivo por el que se ve bien en Chrome pero no en Explorer. Dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer, quizás podrías plantearte no usar flex, y centrar directamente con `text-align:center` (aunque no sé cuál es tu caso específico).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro pero en IE el problema es el valor `space-evenly` de `justify-content`, que no se enfoca en centrar los elementos sino en distribuirlos equitativamente; claro, hay otros bugs y mas pero el Flexbox en general esta muy bien soportado

Comment: @IvanS95 Tienes razón, tenía que haber puesto un enlace más específico. La tercera opción de mi enlace ([la de Flexible Box](https://caniuse.com/#search=flexible%20box)) indica que para versiones antiguas de IE hace falta el prefijo `-ms-` y que IE en general cuenta con numerosos bugs para flexbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según tengo entendido, display flex no funciona en internet explore, creo que solo en edge.
Recuerda que en caso de que tu **div no tenga una altura definida ni un ancho definido** simplemente se usa **margin 0 auto** pero como tu div tiene ambas dimensiones definidas se hace de la siguiente manera:

```css
.padre{
position: relative; /* Se usa para que no se salga la imagen de la caja, ya que la imagen tiene position absolute */
width: 500px;
height: 200px;
background-color: #ddd;
}
.padre img{
position: absolute; /* se usa en caso de este div, donde tiene la altura y el ancho definido, sin esto top, right y left no funcionarían */
width: 100px;
top: 25%; /* sirve en caso de un div como este, donde tiene una altura definida, en caso de que la altura no este definida esta edición no se pone ; */
right: 0; /* se debe usar para que margin 0 auto funcione */
left: 0; /* se debe usar para que margin 0 auto funcione */
margin: 0 auto; /* Esto lo centra */
}
```

```html
<div class="padre">
<img src="https://about.canva.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2016/08/Band-Logo.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

yo las centro usando el siguiente código

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
    .padre{
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
    }   

    .imagen{
        margin:auto;
        display:block;
    }
</style>

<div class="padre">
<img class="imagen" src="https://c.files.bbci.co.uk/AB9D/production/_106433934_ffffff-650-80.jpg" />
</div>
</body>
```

Espero tu calificación.

Comment: Deberías añadir una breve descripción de lo que hace ese código y, a ser posible, adaptarlo al código compartido en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Es sencillo usando margenes automáticos:

```css
.imgUser{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;  
}
.imgUser img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 350px; text-align: center; float: left; background-color: gray; ">

  <div class="imgUser">
    <img src="img.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: No consideras que para optimización de código es mejor margin: 0 auto; que igual hace referencia, a margin-left y margin-right

Comment: Supongo que si, pero ni me planteo optimizaciones de esta índole en css, quizá así veo más claramente a que se refiere el valor... será la costumbre.